# Error while installing React - "Cannot find module 'block-stream'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, npx

1. This is the line executed:

   ```
   PS E:\React_js> npx create-react-app React_js
   node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:942
   throw err;
   ^
   ```
2. The error tells cannot find module:

   > ```
   > Error: Cannot find module 'block-stream'
   > Require stack:
   >  at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:939:15)
   >  at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:780:27)
   >  at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
   >  at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
   >  at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\c67e74de0542c87c\node_modules\tar-pack\node_modules\tar\lib\entry-writer.js:7:19)
   >  at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
   >  at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
   >  at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
   >  at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:827:12)
   >  at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19) {
   >
   >  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND', requireStack: [
   >    'C:\\Users\\DELL\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache\\_npx\\c67e74de0542c87c\\node_modules\\tar-pack\\node_modules\\tar\\lib\\entry-writer.js',
   >    'C:\\Users\\DELL\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache\\_npx\\c67e74de0542c87c\\node_modules\\tar-pack\\node_modules\\tar\\lib\\pack.js',
   >    'C:\\Users\\DELL\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache\\_npx\\c67e74de0542c87c\\node_modules\\tar-pack\\node_modules\\tar\\tar.js',
   >    'C:\\Users\\DELL\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache\\_npx\\c67e74de0542c87c\\node_modules\\tar-pack\\index.js',
   >    'C:\\Users\\DELL\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache\\_npx\\c67e74de0542c87c\\node_modules\\create-react-app\\createReactApp.js',
   >    'C:\\Users\\DELL\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache\\_npx\\c67e74de0542c87c\\node_modules\\create-react-app\\index.js'
   >  ]
   > ```
3. I have tried executing it on both VS and cmd
   *Nodejs version v18.0.0*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be hard to debug as there could be many issues. I suggest going back to step one following the [documentation on `create-react-app`](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started)

As the docs state you need to delete `create-react-app` if you have installed it globally in order to ensure you have the latest version. You can check a globally installed package like so:

```sh
npm list -g create-react-app
```

If it is installed globally, run the uninstall command to remove it:

```sh
npm uninstall -g create-react-app
```

From here you can repeat the steps in the [docs using npx](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started#creating-an-app).

Alternatively, instead of using `npx` you can try with just npm:

```sh
npm install create-react-app && create-react-app React_js
```

If this doesn't work, you can always [try building using yarn](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started#yarn)

Answer (score 0):

If you do run `npm install create-react-app && create-react-app React_js`, make sure you run `npm list -g create-react-app` again

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Go to your `_npx` directory and remove the `c67e74de0542c87c` file ( in your case: )

   ```
   cd C:\\Users\\DELL\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache\\_npx\\
   rmdir c67e74de0542c87c
   ```
2. Run:

   ```
   npx create-react-app
   ```
3. Enter `y` for prompt:

   ```
   Need to install the following packages:
     create-react-app@5.0.1
   Ok to proceed? (y) y
   ```

`create-react-app` should work now.

Answer (score 0):

I ran "npm i block-stream" on the terminal.

Then in my project folder I ran "npx create-react-app" and that worked for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).