# How do I remove the block-stream error so that create-react-app will run

Tags: node.js, reactjs, terminal, react-redux, npx

I am getting this error when trying to start a new project (reddit clone) on react.

npx create-react-app reddit

```
matt@Matthews-MacBook-Pro reddit % npx create-react-app reddit
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1042
  throw err;
  ^
```

```
Error: Cannot find module 'block-stream'
Require stack:
- /Users/matt/.npm/_npx/c67e74de0542c87c/node_modules/tar-pack/node_modules/tar/lib/entry-writer.js
- /Users/matt/.npm/_npx/c67e74de0542c87c/node_modules/tar-pack/node_modules/tar/lib/pack.js
- /Users/matt/.npm/_npx/c67e74de0542c87c/node_modules/tar-pack/node_modules/tar/tar.js
- /Users/matt/.npm/_npx/c67e74de0542c87c/node_modules/tar-pack/index.js
- /Users/matt/.npm/_npx/c67e74de0542c87c/node_modules/create-react-app/createReactApp.js
- /Users/matt/.npm/_npx/c67e74de0542c87c/node_modules/create-react-app/index.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1039:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:885:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/matt/.npm/_npx/c67e74de0542c87c/node_modules/tar-pack/node_modules/tar/lib/entry-writer.js:7:19)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1218:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1272:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1081:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/Users/matt/.npm/_npx/c67e74de0542c87c/node_modules/tar-pack/node_modules/tar/lib/entry-writer.js',
    '/Users/matt/.npm/_npx/c67e74de0542c87c/node_modules/tar-pack/node_modules/tar/lib/pack.js',
    '/Users/matt/.npm/_npx/c67e74de0542c87c/node_modules/tar-pack/node_modules/tar/tar.js',
    '/Users/matt/.npm/_npx/c67e74de0542c87c/node_modules/tar-pack/index.js',
    '/Users/matt/.npm/_npx/c67e74de0542c87c/node_modules/create-react-app/createReactApp.js',
    '/Users/matt/.npm/_npx/c67e74de0542c87c/node_modules/create-react-app/index.js'
  ]
}

Node.js v18.13.0
```

I have uninstalled node through the terminal and also in the folders including lib and bin. I have reinstalled Node. All of the stack references 'npm' which I made sure to check was removed and reinstalled.

The current versions are:

- node v18.13.0
- npm 9.2.0

I found this website in a previous questions, but it relates to Bitcoin Is this needed?:

https://help.blockstream.com/hc/en-us/articles/900001610743-Install-the-Blockstream-Satellite-node-software#:%7E:text=Blockstream%20Satellite%20Kit%20Setup,-Set%20up%20a&text=Blockstream%20maintains%20a%20customized%20version,normal%20Bitcoin%20Core%20node%20does.

"Error: Cannot find module 'block-stream'"
I cannot find any files within directories relating to Block Stream.

I have another error when running "npm install create-react-app reddit"

```
npm WARN deprecated tar@2.2.2: This version of tar is no longer supported, and will not receive security updates. Please upgrade asap.

added 42 packages, changed 1 package, and audited 91 packages in 4s

5 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

3 high severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues, run:
  npm audit fix

Run `npm audit` for details.
matt@Matthews-MacBook-Pro reddit % npm start
npm ERR! Missing script: "start"
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Did you mean one of these?
npm ERR!     npm star # Mark your favorite packages
npm ERR!     npm stars # View packages marked as favorites
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! To see a list of scripts, run:
npm ERR!   npm run

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/matt/.npm/_logs/2023-01-08T17_48_52_057Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error while installing React - "Cannot find module 'block-stream'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72340031/error-while-installing-react-cannot-find-module-block-stream)

Comment: I did try all these steps previously but didn't have any success. Is this suggesting that the problem is with npm?

Comment: So I have fixed it by running npm install react@latest react-dom@latest react-scripts@latest