# React JS Course

Tags: node.js, reactjs, crash

I'm having problems with running a command in my terminal[npx create-react-app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZxHk.png). I am following a video tutorial on react JS crash course, but it was made in Jan, 2021. In my terminal I first run "npm --version" to see what version I have installed. I currently have version 9.6.7, which he explains as long it's above 5.2 it should work. Than i'm ask to run "npx create-react-app". That's when I get an error, "Error: Cannot find module 'block-stream'".[This is the video I am following](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w7ejDZ8SWv8&t=792s&ab_channel=TraversyMedia).

Could you please assist me in resolving this.

Here's a breakdown of what I've done:

I began by checking the version of npm installed on my system using the command "npm --version." As of now, my npm version is 9.6.7.

In the tutorial, the instructor mentioned that as long as my npm version is above 5.2, I should be able to proceed without issues.

The next step involves running the command "npx create-react-app" in the terminal. However, upon executing this command, I encountered an error message: "Error: Cannot find module 'block-stream'."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error while installing React - "Cannot find module 'block-stream'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72340031/error-while-installing-react-cannot-find-module-block-stream)

Answer (score 0):

Delete your project and try running following commands:

```bash
npm uninstall -g create-react-app
```

And then try creating a new project again

```bash
npx create-react-app my-app
```